# Couldn't change gameobject position in other scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton, gameobject

I added score property to my game. But I couldn't find how to change its position when game scene has changed. (in this case score property at right the top of game and I tried to change its position middle of the game)

Here are my codes to move "GameHandler" object (contain score property) to other scene :

```
 private void Awake()
{
    gameHandlerCount = FindObjectsOfType<GameHandler>().Length;

    if (gameHandlerCount > 1)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    else
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
```

(Current position): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFt3W.png [1]

(Goal position): https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwWKp.png [2]

Thanks advance for your interest

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that `Destroy` is delayed and not happening immediately.

This means that `FindObjectsOfType` might still return the destroyed object as well so you might destroy all instances.

---

Instead you can use an actual Singleton Pattern:

```
// public read-only property
public static GameHandler Instance => _instance;

private static GameHandler _instance;

private void Awake()
{
    if(_instance)
    {
        Destroy (gameObject);
        return;
    }

    _instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
}
```

I don't see though where you try to change its position but you could now doing

```
GameHandler.Instance.transform.position = new Vevtor3 (x,y,z);
```

---

Ok so after you added your pictures:

Actually all you want to do is not using the absolute positioning but rather center your score text.

You can do this via the `RectTransform` component by selecting e.g. this option

[image]

you can additionally hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to directly apply the change and pivot settings and set it to the top and center.

Comment: I did what exactly you wrote above. But ıt didn't change anything. Actually I couldn't declare myself well. Sorry. I want the  scoreboard to change when the game scene changes. I added the pictures to explain what I want to do exactly
@derHugo

Comment: @apoleyta97 see the update at the bottom.

Comment: I did. But scoreboard position didn't change. It still appears top right corner of the game. Maybe I should change it via script ? (because game is still on)